# Is it possible ot set up tabjolt on tableau without admin access?

Tags: performance, tableau-api

I am trying to set up tabjolt on one of our tableau servers but i don't have admin access. Using the tabjolt install wizard to connect to a tableau server requires admin access. Is there any way around this? 
If not, I may be able to get it temporally, can i set it up via admin so i can run performance tests as another user after that?

Comment: "set up tabjolt on one of our tableau servers" Installing tabjolt on your Tableau server is not recommended. It's recommended you have a separate injector machine set up and run it there. That doesn't change the nature of you question though but thought I'd mention that tidbit.

Answer (score 1):

tabjolt will require admin access for complete access to Tableau metadata. In the setup docs it states that your admin password will be stored for access to the server. If your admin uses their credentials in the setup process then possibly you could run future tests but I haven't confirmed that.

[image]

Other users can be setup to run load tests on their specific workbooks.

[image: setup user pool]

Keep in mind that you will also need to be logged into the Windows Server with admin access so tabjolt can access Windows Performance metrics.

[tabjolt installation guide](https://github.com/tableau/tabjolt/blob/master/TabJolt%20Installation%20Guide.pdf)